# Repetitive Div Generic

Tags: javascript, razor

I need your help on this. Basically, code below called 4 times as generic section. Each section contains Edit button with Pencil icon. I need to hide the Pencil icon once the user clicks the Edit button (since it will switch to Cancel mode). Can someone help me on this?

```
> <div class="highlighted">
```

> ```
> <span class="float-left paddingleft10"><a class="bold">@Html.Raw(Model.Name)</a></span>    
> @if (Model.IsEditButtonVisible)
> { 
>     <span class="float-left paddingleft20">        
>     <span class="icon pencil float-left"></span>
>     <a class="mode @Model.Mode dark teal section-normal"             href="javascript:void(0);">@Model.EditButton</a>
>     </span><span class="clear-fix"></span>
> }     </div>
> ```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: I am not getting an error. instead using this code  $("span.pencil").addClass('hidden');      hides the entire row in all sections. I need only sepcific section. example, I clicked the edit button in section 1, it will hides only the icon in section 1 and other sections should not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

add js onclick event `onclick="javascript:this.style.display='none';"` to EditButton hyperlink like this

```
     <a class="mode @Model.Mode dark teal section-normal" href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="javascript:this.style.display='none';">@Model.EditButton</a>
```

when you click on this link js fired and will hide your link

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MpF65/)

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately, what I need to hide is the image besides the EditButton and switch the label of editbutton to "Cancel"

Comment: then change onclick function and give your image tag id `onclick="javascript:('your_image_tag_id').style.display='none';"`

Comment: Thanks Satish, but the ICON is referenced as CLASS and needs to go back once the value of the button becomes EDIT again. <span class="icon pencil float-left"></span>

Comment: give a id to this span as follows `<span class="icon pencil float-left" id="your_id"></span>` and use it in your onclick function as i comment earlier.

Comment: Thanks Satish for your help. Kindly confirm this is correct or if I missed something, i you can provide the demo just like that you've provided on your first reply, it would be more help for me.  <span class="icon pencil float-left" id="pencil-span">AAAA</span>
<a class="mode @Model.Mode dark teal section-normal"             href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:'pencil-span'.style.display='none';">@Model.EditButton</a>

Comment: CONT : By the way, please note that this particluar code is enclosed on section and presented as sections right now I have 4 sections. If I clicked the first section, pencil icon of other section should stay

Comment: you need to use id in onclick as follows `<span class="icon pencil float-left" id="pencil-span">AAAA</span> <a class="mode @Model.Mode dark teal section-normal" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('pencil-span').style.display='none';">@Model.EditButton</a>`